# OpenGLES20 screen coordinates to NDC

Tags: android, opengl-es

i want to render an image in OpenGL ES20 for my android app.
Because i am really new to opengl i used a example from [enter link description here](http://androidblog.reindustries.com/)

I already defined objects by using the NDC system [-1, 1]
but in this example you have to define the vertices by using the screen coordinates.
My question now is:
How can i change the screen coordiante system back to the NDC system??

PS: i think the problem lies in this piece of code:

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {      
    // We need to know the current width and height.
    mScreenWidth = width;
    mScreenHeight = height;

    // Redo the Viewport, making it fullscreen.
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    // Clear our matrices
    for(int i=0;i<16;i++)
    {
        mtrxProjection[i] = 0.0f;
        mtrxView[i] = 0.0f;
        mtrxProjectionAndView[i] = 0.0f;
    }

    // Setup our screen width and height for normal sprite translation.
    Matrix.orthoM(mtrxProjection, 0, 0f, width, 0.0f, height, 0, 50);

    // Set the camera position (View matrix)
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mtrxView, 0, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    // Calculate the projection and view transformation
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mtrxProjectionAndView, 0, mtrxProjection, 0, mtrxView, 0);
}
```

Thanks for all answeres!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out how to do it!
So for all who wanna know it:

Matrix.orthoM(mtrxProjection, 0, -1f, 1, -1f, 1, -1, 1);